# BeautifulSoup can't find tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape  data from a website, but the find() method can't find the tag.Below is my code:

```
import urllib2 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://www.jbhifi.com.au/computers/laptop-notebook/'
req=urllib2.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1)          AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36'})
webpage=urllib2.urlopen(req)
content=webpage.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(content)
x=soup.find("div",attrs={'id':'content-two'})
print x  #return None
```

Then, I found out beautiful parser head of HTML only

```
head=soup.find('head')
print head # print out content within <head>tag
body=soup.find('body')
print body # Print None
```

I am really confused. I have used beautifulsoup couple times before.This is first time I met this problem.  Anyone knows how to fix this problem? Thank you.

**The problem has been solved.** I uninstalled beautifulsoup 4.2 and then install beautifulsoup 4.3. The code works now.

Comment: What do you actually wanna scrape from the website?

Answer (score 2):

The code is working very well. Your assumption that 'x' would return None is wrong.

```
(Pdb) print x is None
False
(Pdb) print str(x)[:100]
<div id="content-two" style="float:right;width:828px;">
<div style="padding-bottom:7px;"><a href="ht
```

Comment: I have tried again, but I still can't get the tag. soup.find("div",attrs={'id':'content-two'}) return NoneType value.

Comment: I uninstalled bs4.2 and install 4.3. The code works now! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can check.

Make sure that the code you want to parse is on page

*`view-source:chrome-extension://http://www.jbhifi.com.au/computers/laptop-notebook/`*

If no exist, html code is create by javascript.

this case. using selenium or find the part that generates html code with javascript.

---

There are two ways to generate HTML code in JavaScript.

fisrt way, generates html code with javascript => recommend **selenium** + **bs4** + **requests**

second way, generates html code with javascript after data receive on server => recommend **bs4** + **requests**